# Sphere collider but hollow inside

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I want the sphere 2 to be hollow inside, so that the sphere 1 can proceed physics inside.
[image]

But I don't know which collider to use.

[image]

Comment: So you want a dognut.   You can make mesh shapes colliders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a Sphere in a 3D modelling software and invert the normals so that they face inside the sphere. in unity place the sphere with the inverted normals as a child to your hollow sphere. this will represent now the inner side of your hollow sphere. remove the meshrenderer and add a meshcollider to the sphere with the inverted normals. now you can place any object with a rigidbody component attached to it inside and it will collide with the inner side of your sphere.

[sphere with innerside to collide with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9eHh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse `Normals` and use `MeshCollider` to fix problem.

[image]